# Makefiles: specific 'no input files', automatic variables

Tags: c++, makefile, automatic-variable

I'm new to makefiles, and they puzzle me. I have the following folder hierarchy:

A folder named `lib` contains tow folders: `include` (with file `mylib.h`) and `src` (with file `mylib.cpp`). It also contains a Makefile, which, for some reason, gives me an error.

The full makefile is:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC
OBJECTS = mylib.o

all: libmine.so

libmine.so: $(OBJECTS)
            g++ -shared $(CFLAGS) \
            -o libmine.so \
            $(OBJECTS)

%.o:        src/%.cpp include/%.h
            g++ $(CFLAGS) \
            -I include \
            -o %.o \
            -c src/%.cpp

clean:
            rm src/*.o
            rm libmine.so
```

The error is

```
mr209@Quantum:~/Desktop/hw1/lib$ make
g++ -Wall -fPIC \
            -I include \
            -o %.o \
            -c src/%.cpp
g++: error: src/%.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mylib.o] Error 4
```

But the file **is** present. Thus, `make` is doing weird things, causing it not to be able to find the `.cpp` file.

In order to make `libmine.so`, `g++` will have to do something with `mylib.o`, and for a generic `.o` file I have written some lines of code.

Here is what I was thinking: in order to make `libmine.so`, `g++` will have to do something with `mylib.o`. Thus, in `lib`, a file named `mylib.o` has to appear. Using the generic `%.0` rule, this file is made from `mylib.cpp` in `src` and `mylib.h` in `include` (hence the first line of the `%.o` rule). The file is made using `g++`, which has to look in `include` for additional headers, produces `mylib.o` as output, and compiles `src/mylib.cpp`, but `-c` guarantees that a `.o` file is produced.

Obviously, something goes wrong, and I am unable to figure out what. Only 2 days ago have I learned what Makefiles are and why one should learn how to deal with them, so I'm not that much of an expert.

Answer (score 2):

Your build target `%.o` is miswritten. You can't use the `%` in the command section, so the names of the destination file and dependent file won't ever match.

The proper change is to do the following:

```
%.o: src/%.cpp include/%.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) \
    -I include \
    -o $@ \
    -c src/$(@:%.o=%.cpp)
```

Just to explain the changes, the `-o` needs the target file, which is pretty much always written as `$@` in Makefiles, as that's the name of the target.

Secondly, the source file needs to be defined in terms of the target, the operator in question is a pattern replacement operator `$(@:%.o=%.cpp)`, so what that does is take the target - which will match a filename of `<blah>.o`, then it pattern match replaces `.o` with `.cpp`.

So in the case of the target `mylib.o`, the variable `$@` is `mylib.o`, and the result of doing `$(@:%.o=%.cpp)` is to turn `mylib.o` into `mylib.cpp`. As a result it is the expected file that is being compiled, and the expected target is build.

Rules using a `%` pattern in them are what are referred to as implicit rules, and are used to reduce the complexity of the code being written - if you had a pile of files that shared the target pattern: `blah.o: src/blah.cpp src/blah.h`, then you use the implicit rule to only have to write the target once, then you need to write the commands in terms of the target.

Answer (score 0):

You must do a variable before put it in g++
like :

`FT_C= $(src/%.cpp)
FT_O=$(FT_C:.c=.o)`

and

`g++ $(CFLAGS) -I include -o $(FT_O) -c $(FT_C)`

and don't put your .h in compilation '-I' are here for it.

Look this example if you want understand what i mean:

https://github.com/emericspiroux/wolf3d/blob/master/libft/Makefile